# Select the highest difference value between two columns

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Table:

```
| Server ID | Total HDD Space | Used HDD Space |
|   alpha   |      1000       |      10        |
|   bravo   |      1500       |     1000       |
```

I need to select the server with the highest free space available.

My attempt,

```
server = Server.objects.filter(free_space=(F('total_space')-F('used_space'))).order_by('-free_space')[:1]
```

gave this error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'free_space' into field. Choices are: image, name, total_space, used_space
```

I also tried this way:

```
server = Server.objects.filter(**{'free_space': (F('total_space')-F('used_space'))}).order_by('-free_space')[:1]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Django 1.8, which has new query functionality ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#query-expressions-conditional-expressions-and-database-functions)).

```
servers = Server.objects.annotate(free_space=(F('total_space')-F('used_space'))).order_by('free_space')
```

On earlier versions of Django, you could use [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra).

```
servers = Server.objects.extra(select={'free_space': 'total_space-used_space'}, order_by=['-free_space'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Alasdair reply is correct. Alternatively, you might want to simply cache the difference in a new column:

```
class Server(models.Model):
    total_hdd_space = models.PositiveIntegerField(...)
    used_hdd_space = models.PositiveIntegerField(...)
    free_hdd_space = models.PositiveIntegerField(...)

    def save(*args, **kwargs):
         self.free_hdd_space = self.total_hdd_space - self.used_hdd_space
         super(Server, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

That would make the query faster but takes more space.